# can't seem to link GLFW library

Tags: c++, linker-errors, glfw

I'm attempting to make my own game engine and using this video tutorial to do so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pid8JGlBdPY&t=1122s&ab_channel=TheCherno

I'm using library called GLFW. I linked everything as its shown in the video triple checked everything but every time I use function from the library I get errors. [image]

this is all the code I've written

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        cout << "NOPE" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing I've linked something wrong even though I can't find what. but if that's not the issue here and im missing something, please let me know. I don't really know what those errors mean.

Comment: The first error in that list is very important. Are you mixing Debug and Release?

Comment: if you mean this https://i.imgur.com/VLadAUZ.png I've linked them in debug. not in release

Comment: Is  your compiler VS 2013? If not the compiled binaries will not work. VS 2015 to 2019 are binary compatible with each other but not compatible with any other version.

Comment: uh I see. I'm using VS 2019. thanks

Comment: You need binaries that are compatible with Visual Studio 2015 to 2019.

Comment: I changed library version to 2019 and now it works. thank you